# Conditional GROUP BY with custom variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I want to use a variable to determine conditional GROUP BY in my SQL statement like so:

```
group by
case when (@GroupByFirst is not null) then a.Name else b.Name end
```

Unfortunately I get an error that a.Name is

```
invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

Is there any solution to make it work. Forgot to mention, SQL is part of stored procedure, but it shouldn't make any difference I believe

Comment: can you show your whole statement?

Comment: What is the whole query ?

Comment: The query is quite long but that's an example giving the same error:
declare @GroupByFirst int = 1
select 
sa.Name,
count(p.Id)
from Property p
inner join PropertyInfo pinfo on pinfo.Id = p.LiveInfoId
inner join SolicitorAccount sa on pinfo.SolicitorAccountId = sa.Id
group by
case when (@GroupByFirst is not null) then sa.Name else sa.Name end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look like:

```
select (case when (@GroupByFirst is not null) then a.Name else b.Name end) as name
from . . .
group by (case when (@GroupByFirst is not null) then a.Name else b.Name end)
```

You cannot refer to either `a.Name` nor `b.Name` in the `SELECT` (without an aggregation function, that is).  You can use the expression.

Answer (score 0):

declare @GroupByFirst varchar(30)='s'

select max(someval) from Login_Master
group by
case when @GroupByFirst is not null then a.Name else b.Name end

Answer (score 0):

Add @GroupByFirst case statement in SELECT statement to avoid the issue. SELECT statement should contain the column/variable/statement which is used in GROUP BY Clause.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the comparison within a subquery and then grouping the values.

```
SELECT subQuery.Name
FROM
  (SELECT (CASE WHEN (@GroupByFirst IS NOT NULL) THEN a.Name ELSE b.Name END) AS name
   FROM . . .) AS subQuery
GROUP BY subQuery.Name
```